# Are thunderbolt interfaces / external drives supported?

Tags: system-installation

I will be trying it on a Mac Mini. I have 12TB of external thunderbolt storage attached to the mac hence the thunderbolt support will be absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Thunderbolt works but Thunderbolt 3 may have issues. You better boot a live USB and check it out yourself.